# Haskell - Arbol binario - Cambiar una variable en un arbol por otro arbol

Tags: haskell

tengo este arbol llamado arb

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este otro llamado arbAux

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y pongo una funcion de sustituir variable eje: sustituirVariable "d" arbAux arb

entonces deberia de cambiar la "d" por el arbAux

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que tengo de codigo es esto

```
type Op = String -- operacion puede ser + - *
type Exp = String -- Exprecion es una variable

data Arbol = Hoja Exp | Nodo Op Arbol Arbol

-- caso de ambos con dos hojas

sustVar::Variable -> Arbol -> Arbol -> Arbol
sustVar var (Hoja e) (Hoja exp) = if (exp == var) then let exp = var
                                                        else exp
```

Please!!! Peguenme una ayudita :) ese codigo me da error -.-

```
codigo.hs:159:113: error: parse error on input ‘else’
|
|                                                       else exp
|                                                       ^^^^
```

Comment: Hola Andrey, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Deberías intentar ofrecer una pregunta más clara y con el código bien formateado para que pueda ser bien interpretada por la comunidad. Para ello, te recomiendo que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para más información y que completes el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender más sobre el sitio. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola @Andrey_Rojas . He tenido que formatear el código para que se vea claro. Intenta que el código sea completo, ya que en el fragmento que has puesto faltan cosas como qué es una `Variable`. El error sale porque estas usando mal `let`, no es para alterar valores. En programación funcional nunca se alteran los valores. Revisa la documentación sobre cómo se usan `let` y `if..then..else`.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes usar `let` sin su correspondiente `in` (salvo en los bloques `do`)